# What does the system call in do in the following program?

Tags: c

```
read(fileno(stdin), passwd, 1024);
if(strcmp(passwd, real_password) == 0) {
    printf("\n\nWelcome back :)\n\n~$ ");
    fflush(stdout);
    system("/bin/bash -p");
```

So I have this program and I want to know what does the system("/bin/bash -p") call do in the program?

Answer (score 0):

It executes `bash` with the parameter `-p`. The path of pass is `/bin/bash`, according to the code.

Check the ref of [system()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html):

> DESCRIPTION

```
   The system() library function uses fork(2) to create a child process
   that executes the shell command specified in command using execl(3)
   as follows:

       execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) 0);

   system() returns after the command has been completed.
```

The `-p` parameter, according to ref of [bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> The -p option changes the output format to that specified by POSIX

Comment: and what will that do. Executing bash with the parameter -p

Comment: That's what `system()` does @follower. Hope that helps.

Comment: I just fail to understand what is the significance of this call

Comment: Without it `bash` won't be executed. Obviously the code you have has this intention @follower.